# How can I show $f(z)=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ is not differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I know that: $f(z)=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}= \sqrt{r}\cos(\theta/2)+i\sqrt{r}\sin(\theta/2)$. I was trying to write $f'$ using the components functions and then show $f'$ does not exist at $z=0$, but I am not sure about how to do this. Thanks for the help!

UPDATE. Is the following reasoning ok?
If $f$ is analytic at $z=0$, then it is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z=0$, which means it's differentiable at every real number $x$ close enough to $0$, but this is impossible because the real variable function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: well for a start notice that for $z$ being real the function is not differentiable at $0$, do you know why $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ admit no derivative at $0$ ?

Comment: Understood, thanks Omar. How would you write $f'$ though? just differentiate both components functions with respect to $r$?

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative (the limit) and by using the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument prove that there is an $\epsilon$ such that for every $\delta$ the limit does not converge.

Comment: You can follow Ali's hint, but I pointed out an easy argument, I'll give you another hint, a complex function is differentiable if and only if it is differentiable in every direction (any line passing through your complex number in the plane)

Comment: @Omar That is not correct. It is not enough that the limit of the difference quotient exists  along every ray. In the definition of complex differentiability, you can approach the point in any way you want not just along rays. What you claim is a necessary condition but not a sufficient one.

Comment: yes my mistake, I meant he can use the real line here as he just need to prove non differentiability

Comment: can you confirm something? let us say that I proved that $f$ is differentiable along every line, and that the directional derivative is some function of $arg(z)$ itself continuous, is it sufficient to claim that $f$ is differentiable ?

Comment: @Omar No: The function $f(z) = \bar{z}$ has directional derivative $e^{-i \arg(z)}$ which is continuous in $\arg(z)$ and is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: The updated argument is OK.

Comment: I have one question so I can start solving your question. Are $r=|z|$ and $\theta= \arg{z}$ ?

Comment: The value of $f$ depends on how you pick the argument $\theta$. If you choose $0\le \theta < 2\pi$, you get a different function than if you pick $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$. And here you see the reason it isn't differentiable at $0$. It is also not differentiable, nor even continuous along the ray in the direction where $\theta$ suddenly jumps in value. This is just the function $f(z) = \sqrt z$, and I can only presume that the intent was to make the definition of that function definite. But since the restrictions on $\theta$ are not given, it remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})=\sqrt{r}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta/2}$, then
$$
f^2(z)=z.
$$
Hence, if $f$ is analytic in $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$, then
$$
2f(z)f'(z)=1.
$$
If $0\in\Omega$, then
$$
2f(0)f'(0)=1,
$$
which is IMPOSSIBLE since $f(0)=0$.

Thus, $f$ can not be analytic at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sqrt z-\sqrt0}{z-0}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac1{\sqrt z}$$ does not exist.

In the polar form

$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\sqrt re^{i\theta/2}-\sqrt0}{re^{i\theta}-0}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{e^{i\theta/2}}{\sqrt r}$$ does not exist.

But it is enough to say that the derivatives does not exist in the reals.